Find the edo solution $x\left( \frac{dy}{dx}\right) ^{3}-y\left( \frac{dy}{dx}\right) ^{2}+1=0$
I was able to show that one of the solutions is $y\left( x\right) =cx+
\frac{1}{c^{2}}$. But I was not able to show that $y\left( x\right) =\sqrt[3%
]{2x^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^{2}}{4}}$ is also a solution. What I was able to show is that $y\left( x\right) =\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}$ is also a solution.

$$
\sqrt[3]{2x^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^{2}}{4}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{8x^{2}}{4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^{2}}{4}}=2\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^{2}}{4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^{2}}{4}}
=\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}
$$

You already have all the solutions of the ODE.

Did you mean ODE where you typed edo in the title?  And why did you also tag this [tag:partial-differential-equations]?

this is Clairaut ode. So it will have a general solution and singular solution(s).
Solve
\begin{align*}
x {y^{\prime}}^{3}-y {y^{\prime}}^{2}+1&=0
\end{align*}
This is Clairaut ODE. It has the form
\begin{align*}
y&=x y^{\prime}+g\left(y^{\prime}\right)
\end{align*}
Where $g$ is function of $y'(x)$.
Let $p=y^{\prime}$ the ode becomes
\begin{align*}
x \,p^{3}-y \,p^{2}+1 = 0
\end{align*}
Solving for $y$ from the above results in
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{x \,p^{3}+1}{p^{2}}\tag{1A} 
\end{align*}
The above ode is a Clairaut ode which is now solved.
We start by replacing $y^{\prime}$ by $p$ which gives
\begin{align*}
y&=p x +\frac{1}{p^{2}}\\ 
&=p x +\frac{1}{p^{2}}
\end{align*}
Writing the ode as
\begin{align*}
y&= p x +g \left(p \right)
\end{align*}
We now write $g\equiv g\left(  p\right)  $ to make notation simpler but we should
always remember that  $g$ is function of $p$ which in turn is function of $x$. Hence the above becomes
\begin{align*}
y = p x +g\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Then we see that
\begin{align*}
g&=\frac{1}{p^{2}}
\end{align*}
Taking derivative of (1) w.r.t. $x$ gives
\begin{align*}
p  &=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x p+g\right)  \\ 
p  & =\left(  p+x\frac{dp}{dx}\right)  +\left(  g' \frac{dp}{dx}\right)  \\ 
p  & =p+\left(  x+g'\right)  \frac{dp}{dx}\\ 
0  & =\left(  x+g'\right)  \frac{dp}{dx}
\end{align*}
Where $g'$ is derivative of $g\left(  p\right)  $ w.r.t. $p$. The general solution is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{dp}{dx} &  =0\\ 
p &=c_{1}
\end{align*}
Substituting this in (1) gives the general solution as
\begin{align*}
y = c_{1} x +\frac{1}{c_{1}^{2}}
\end{align*}
The singular solution is found from solving for $p$ from
\begin{align*}
x+g'\left(  p\right) &=0
\end{align*}
And substituting the result back in (1). Since we found above that  $g=\frac{1}{p^{2}}$, then the above equation becomes
\begin{align*}
x+g'\left(  p\right) &= x -\frac{2}{p^{3}}\\ 
&= 0
\end{align*}
Solving the above for $p$ results in
\begin{align*}
p_{1} &=\frac{2^{{1}/{3}} \left(x^{2}\right)^{{1}/{3}}}{x}\\ 
p_{2} &=-\frac{2^{{1}/{3}} \left(x^{2}\right)^{{1}/{3}}}{2 x}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}\, 2^{{1}/{3}} \left(x^{2}\right)^{{1}/{3}}}{2 x}\\ 
p_{3} &=-\frac{2^{{1}/{3}} \left(x^{2}\right)^{{1}/{3}}}{2 x}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}\, 2^{{1}/{3}} \left(x^{2}\right)^{{1}/{3}}}{2 x}
\end{align*}
Substituting the above back in (1) results in these singular solutions.
\begin{align*}
y_{1} &=\frac{3 x^{2} 2^{{1}/{3}}}{2 \left(x^{2}\right)^{{2}/{3}}}\\ 
y_{2} &=-\frac{3 x^{2} 2^{{1}/{3}}}{\left(x^{2}\right)^{{2}/{3}} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}\\ 
y_{3} &=\frac{3 x^{2} 2^{{1}/{3}}}{\left(x^{2}\right)^{{2}/{3}} \left(i \sqrt{3}-1\right)}
\end{align*}
So there are 4 solutions. One is general and three are singular.
